# Decode Special ByteString b'\x01\x01\x01\x02

Tags: arrays, parsing, bytecode, steam-web-api

I've tryed all decodings codecs and stuff, but still I can't manage to decode this properly:
`b'\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x02\x01\x02\x039\x9cGl\x04\xf0gv\x88\x10Namalsk Survival\x0cn\xfc\xd7\x04ITv\x88\x0eNamalsk Island\x81\x1a\nt\x04\x04\xb0\xef\\\x13Community Framework\x03\x04dayz\x0eJacob_Mango_V3\x06sumrak'`

The only decoding codec almost working is asciim which give me this:

`

```
                     nITvNamalsk Island
t\Community FrameworkdayzJacob_Mango_V3sumrak
```

`

But as you can see, it's still not readable and even not working with bigger strings.

Any help to decode this could be great and help the steam community for DayZ as they changed the way A2S_RULES work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This obviously isn’t text, so trying text encodings won’t help you. This is binary data that just happens to have some strings embedded. There is no way to guess a binary format from a single example. One observation is that each string is preceded by a byte telling its length. But this emphasizes even more that these are five individual strings embedded in a binary format, in other words, the other bytes are not text data.